# How to make zappa work with my python 3.9 version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, zappa, python-zappa

I am trying to do `zappa init` but unfortunately I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/zappa", line 5, in <module>
    from zappa.cli import handle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zappa/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(err_msg)
RuntimeError: This version of Python (3.9) is not supported!
Zappa (and AWS Lambda) support the following versions of Python: ['3.6', '3.7', '3.8']
```

As you can see my version of python is `3.9` . I installed `pyenv` to make it works with `3.8` but it still doesn't work.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

AWS lambda currently does not support python 3.9.
You can see a list of supported runtimes here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html

Comment: It does actually support Python 3.9 - you should update your answer @mRyan

Comment: At the time of writing AWS lambda didn't support Python3.9. Since this has only just recently been updated the Zappa readme seems to suggest it only supports up to 3.8
"make sure you are running Python 3.6/3.7/3.8"
https://github.com/zappa/Zappa#installation-and-configuration

Comment: https://github.com/zappa/Zappa/pull/1026 any day now :)